# Turtlebot arm Catkin error

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, catkin, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My ros version is Hydro, and I cannot find any tutorials for Hydro so I followed groove version on wiki, but when I get to the catkin make part, the terminal comes with these error, Can any one guide me how to fix it plz.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:159 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'moveit_core' which must be find_package()-ed
  before.  If it is a catkin package it can be declared as CATKIN_DEPENDS
  instead without find_package()-ing it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  turtlebot_arm/turtlebot_arm_block_manipulation/CMakeLists.txt:23 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I found out that when I run `git clone https://github.com/corot/turtlebot_arm`
it was copied from github 'indigo' branch, I don't know. Plz some one help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231475/turtlebot-arm-catkin-error/) by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According the the [README](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm/blob/indigo-devel/README.md), that version should work on Hydro, as well.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-04-10**:
Yeah, but I don't know if I need to install sth about MoveIt bcz of the error comments. Have you work with sth similar before? Plz guide me. Thank you so much!!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-04-11**:
It is the Indigo version that says it should work on Hydro. Did you use `rosdep` to install all the dependencies?

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-04-11**:
Should I follow the Indigo version tutorials on wiki? or fuerte version?